# How to place content below a position absolute item

Tags: html, css, overlapping

I'm not sure how to ask this questions but I will try my best to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.I have a banner on my homepage and inside this banner I have a div that is overlapping it.

Now, by overlapping this item over the banner It creates a problem where all other content on my homepage is going behind this overlapped item.. Example: my footer (which is marked in red) is going behind this overlapped item and I want to stop this from happening, I want all contents to go below it.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    color: #444;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    height: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

secion {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 168px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16);
}

.top-nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    background-color: white;
}

.top-nav ul {
    float: left;
    line-height: 42px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.top-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.top-nav ul li a, a:visited {
    color: #444;
    padding: 42px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top-nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

.center-console {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

header nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

header nav ul {
    float: left;
    line-height: 46px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a, a:visited {
    color: #444;
    padding: 46px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.54);
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #15c;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #dcdcdc;
}


.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.center-console form {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.search-icon-small {
    width: 18px;
    height: 19px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 11px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("../images/search-icon-small.png");
}

header form input[type=text] {
    border: 0;
    width: 342px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}


.shopping-cart {
    width: 38px;
    height: 32px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("../images/shopping-cart.png");
    background-position:bottom;
}

.item-count {
    color: #fff;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4683ea;
}


/*** Homepage ***/

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 480px;
    background-color: #4387fd;
}

.banner form {
    width: 880px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-top: 228px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.search-icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("../images/search-icon.png");
}

.banner form input[type=text] {
    border: 0;
    width: 805px;
    height: 50px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.featured-items {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 358px;
    padding: 21px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.featured-items ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.featured-items ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 214px;
    height: 214px;
    margin-right: 22px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.featured-items ul li:last-child {
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BasicOffer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="top-nav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Selling</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul style="float:right;">
                    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="center-console">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo"></div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
                    <div class="search-icon-small"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Health & Beauty</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Household Supplies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Baby & Toddler</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home & Garden</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pet Supplies</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="shopping-cart">
                    <div class="item-count">11</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
                <div class="search-icon"></div>
            </form>
            <div class="featured-items">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>This will be the footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Design:

[image]

Thanks,
Richard.

Comment: share design or share reference URL

Comment: @DevKiran The entire page is there. You can run the code snippet and see the footer market in red going behind the white div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using absolute position. you can try

```
margin-top: -150px;
position: relative;
```

[working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jSYGo32mr4jswL8uaaP3?p=preview)

Comment: Ohh he wanted the other elements to get vertically pushed down on the page. Kudos on understanding the question!

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why absolute positioning is needed in this example, but I recommend you look into using `position: relative` for the content block that follows the banner.

Relative positioning behaves mostly like the default (static) when it comes to layout flow, but it supports the z-index layering like absolute positioning. (Considering using relative position also on the banner if you don't really need it to be absolutely positioned.)

Comment: Thank you, I was messing around with it trying to fix the issue. That's why the absolute positioning is there. The Position Relative didn't do any good, the content such as my footer (in red) is still going under it.

Comment: Hmm... If I open your example right here in SO, inspect the red footer element in devtools and add `position:relative`, it pops above the banner with the 3 gray boxes. Is that not what you were going for?

Comment: No sir, I never said anything about wanting it "above" I said "below it". Anyhow, I really appreciate you trying to help and I've added a screenshot of my design. Notice where the red footer element is located. It's under the white box with the grey elements inside. Other words "Below" the white box with the grey elements inside.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yep, sorry I misunderstood your intent. The answer posted by amansoni211 is solid.